# programmatically update Autolayout Constraints which is set via Inspector

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which has a tableview in it. I set its autolayout manually. Now I'm trying to change the autolayout constraints programmatically. How can I do that?

This is my code's [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Lox.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can change constraints programatically without any outlet:

```
for (_, value) in self.view.constraints.enumerate() {
        let constraint = value as NSLayoutConstraint

        if constraint == .Height {
            if value.firstItem.isEqual(self.tableView) {
                constraint.constant = 200.0
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks body you save my time

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. Just select the constraint you want to update progrmatically eg. height
2. create an outlet of it. New referencing outlet. 
    [image]
3. eg. `@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`
4. update constant, `heightConstraint.constant = 100.`

Comment: i try to change the top space between view & tableview. i make a outlet constrain topSpace & set topSpace.constant = 250.0 but nothing happened. Basically i tried to make a gap between view & tableview.

Comment: `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` you need to update constraint as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set up outlets for the constraints you need to modify and hook them up.

Comment: i tried but noting happend. 
topSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tableView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 300)

here topSpace is an outlet

Comment: That's replacing a constraint with a new one.  That's not modifying an existing constraint.

Comment: topSpace.constant = 300.0 not modifying the space between view & tableview.